# Jquery UI animations do not occur on hidden elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In HTML, when I hide DOM element, jQuery UI is sometimes not working.

For example, `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()` will fail to run.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Post the code so that we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because jqueryui sometimes not working with hidden element.
So when you want to use JqueryUI, first you have to display hidden element and then slidedown.